# What does "An Introduction to X" mean?

Tags: soft-question

Is my understanding correct that when a textbook is called something along the lines of "An Introduction to X", it contains the basic results of X (roughly speaking)? If not, what does such a title mean?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Most English words are not well-defined.  But we still use a dictionary...

Comment: For the most part the answer is YES, but sometimes fairly advanced books can have "introduction to" in their titles! For examples of mathematics books with "introduction to" in their titles, see [this google-book search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=subject:%22mathematics%22+intitle:Introduction+intitle:to).

Comment: It's not always clear which of the results of X should be called "basic".  As a first approximation, one might take those results that are covered in a typical text entitled "Introduction to X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it contains a large portion of the basic results of X, but not necessarily in a simpler language.

Comment: I agree. I've edited my answer. Thank you.